# implementation hysteresis in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I am trying  to solve a hysteresis problem. Considering hysteresis effect, the moisture content is history dependent: Consider a block of wood, which has initial moisture content w0, which is in equilibrium with initial environment of phi0; then you put the block into environment of phi1; now you need (w0, phi0 and phi1) to determine w1 corresponding to phi1; then you put the block into environment of phi2, to determine w2 corresponding to phi2, you need (w1, phi1 and phi2);....
In Modelica, you can only use the state variable at current time step; how can I use phi0 and phi1 simultaneously? not the time derivative of phi, der(phi). when w1 is determined, the values of w1 and phi1 will be transferred to w0 and phi0.
http://vbn.aau.dk/ws/files/13648994/Selected_Constitutive_Models_for_Simulating_the_Hygromechanical_Response_of_Wood
sorry I cannot upload an image, I upload the link of a paper, please check the Fig.6 and equation 17 in page 65 (90/135)

Sorry, I don't know whether it is clear or not. I want to implement sorption hysteresis in Modelica. Hysteresis is history dependent, I need the previous state as input to calculate current state variables. The lower continuous line is adsorption curve, upper continuous line is desorption curve, these two curves are function of relative humidity h, they are known; s(h)=(w[h]-wads[h])/(wdes[h]-wads[h]). z0 (h0,m0) is initial/previous moisture state (can be given by initial condition or calculated results from previous time step.) if the current h is bigger than h0, moisture state at zd0(relative humidity hd0) will be calculated from moisture state z0, then the curve along zd0-z0-right arrow will be defined as a function of hd0; now I want to calculate moisture content at current h (h>h0) on the defined curve zd0-z0-right arrow; but I cannot provide both h0 and h in the Modelica code. I define h as current state, I need the moisture state at previous time step h0. And every time step, when the moisture state at h is calculated (m at h are obtained, the values of m and h will be transferred to m0 and h0 for calculation in next time step.)

Comment: Xiaobo, your question (and its context) is not very clear. Please explain what you are trying to model?

Comment: Does this help? http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/discrete/hysteresis/

Comment: To my knowledge the general case of memory in a dynamic equation can't be solved in modelica (declarative). Maybe in your case of hysteresis you can: proceed as in block "Modelica.Blocks.Logical.Hysteresis".
So you try to use a logical boolean variable y which contains the direction. You can use "pre(y)". 
In the continuous equation the memory must be eliminated by differentiation and a condition over y.

Comment: In the paper (p 91/135) there is a section with the equations to be implemented - including the hysteresis function (eq. 28). I assume the partial derivatives (eq. 26-28) are functions material properties and can be estimated with a difference quotient. Have you tried to implement these equations directly in Modelica?

Comment: Thanks, Justnielsen. Yes, I have tried to implement theses equations directly in Modelica. In equation 28, h is relative humidity at current time step, hd0 and ha0 have to be calculated from previous time step (h0, w0); then the equations cannot be correctly implemented.

Comment: Thanks, Matth, I have read this example, however, it does help for my problem.

Comment: Thanks, user3174640. I will try to find out whether logical Boolean variable can solve my problem.